# In a column, fill values that are not a number with "NaN"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a certain column with values as below:

```
index     some_column
 0          12345
 1          23549
 2          .....
 3          78516
 4          98713
 5          .....
```

I want to check the values in the column and if the value is not a number (i.e. if the value is "....."), then I want to fill that value with np.NaN.

I've tried the function below:

```
from numbers import Number
def fill_in(values):
    if isinstance(values, Number) == False:
        return np.NaN
```

then I use the `.apply` function on the column:

```
df['some_column'].apply(fill_in)
```

I expected:

```
index     some_column
 0          12345
 1          23549
 2          NaN
 3          78516
 4          98713
 5          NaN
```

But instead got:

```
index     some_column
 0          NaN
 1          NaN
 2          NaN
 3          NaN
 4          NaN
 5          NaN
```

Can someone please explain to me why I thought wrong?

Comment: you shouldn't be checking if the value *is* a number, but rather if it can be converted to what you consider to be a number. Python is duct typed, so your DF can have literally anything inside of it. The column could contain only strings that looks like numbers for all we know.

Comment: @TaylorCochran [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), not duct typing.

Comment: To expand on what Taylor mentioned - it looks like, in your case, the values printed as numbers are just strings of digits. Therefore, they fail the `isinstance` test. You should instead check if the values *could* be numbers at all. You could use the `str.isnumeric()` method or try casting the value to a numeric type and catch exceptions.

Comment: @TaylorCochran  For this particular example, I ran a type check on the values in the column and all the numbers return type "int", while all the "....." return type "str".

Comment: @skuzzy If I try the str.isnumeric() method then Python returns an error saying " 'int' object has no attribute 'str' " because some of the values in the column are type 'int'.

Comment: @bphung2 The primary error related to your case is that you have a return value for only one part of the conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function supplied to `apply` must have a return value for all inputs.
In your case, there is no return value if the `if` test fails.

In your case when pandas does not get a value returned from the function, it makes up the output as `NaN` since it has nothing to put there.

Adding that negative test return value should get you the desired output.

```
def fill_in(value):
    if isinstance(value, Number) == False:
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: This works, but I don't know why it only works after i change "if isinstance(value, Number) == False" to "if isinstance(value, str) == True" (and not the other way around). Thanks a ton!